# Android TextView size not changing with longer text

Tags: android, textview

So I'm using a custom layout for my ActionBar with a textView and indicator image in it's center.

An activity uses a pager for reading, with what amounts to a "next" button at the end of the pager. When that button is pressed, the pager loads the next item and changes the actionBar's text.

Change code here:

```
private void moveToNextBook(){
    String title = chapters.get(0).getTitle(context);
    titleTextView.setText(title);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    ((ViewPager) this.container).setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

The problem is that the textView's size (width) doesn't seem to be changing with setText() so if the new title is longer than the old title, the text gets cut off.

I've tried invalidate(), forceLayout(), and a few other things and nothings seems to be working.

If anyone know why it's not automatically changing, that would be great. Otherwise something to force it to completely reload while acknowledging the change in text (preferably without reloading the entire activity) would work as well

layout xml with the relevant content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/language_button_click"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="chapterButtonClicked"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/middle_button_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title_font_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/quickaction_arrow_down"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm running into a very very similar issue.  We have a recyclerview, when the recyclerview is scroll, we update a textview to reflect which item is selected.  This is called from a callback from within the LayoutManager and called from the onLayoutChildren method.  Right now our solution is to set the width to be match_parent, but I don't like that fix at all.